# Selecting multiple photos on the HTC One X (AT&T)

Tags: gallery, htc-one-x

I just received the HTC One X from AT&T. How can I select multiple photos in the Gallery?

Comment: Have you tried long-pressing (tap and hold) on an individual photo? On the vanilla Gallery that will enable multi-select mode.

Comment: @eldarerathis That doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 2):

My experience of the One X in order to be able to select multiple items in the gallery you need to first give it a task to do.

For example,

- Open Gallery
- Hit 'Share' in the bottom left, you'll need a service which takes multiple uploads, such as Facebook
- Then you'll see the 'multi-select' grid with tick boxes next to each image which you can then select.

As far as I can see from playing on my device for 10 minutes, there isn't a general 'multi-select' feature. You might try a different gallery app though. I would recommend [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try any Third party Gallery apps like [QuickPic Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en).

Answer (score -1):

I think multiple selection is (Programmatically) supported in KitKat and newer versions of Android as given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486080/android-how-to-launch-the-device-file-system-programmatically).